# Vim: how to dynamically create regex pattern

Tags: vim, vi

I would like to concatenate a variable into a regex pattern. For example, considering this pattern for syntax that matches lines from 1 to 3.

`syn match Title /\%>0l\%<4l.*/`

I would like to be able to dynamically set the second integer in the pattern (the '4' in the above example to whatever the value of `b:title_until` is). I have tried with string concatenation but it does not work. The intention should be clear in the example below:

```
let b:title_until = 10

if exists("b:title_until")
  syn match Title "/\%>0l\%<" + b:title_until + "l.*/"
end
----------------------------------------------------------------------
> (NFA) Unknown operator '\%
> Invalid character after \%
> Invalid argument: Title "/\%>0l\%<" + b:title_until + "l.*/"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### General theory

Vimscript is evaluated exactly like the Ex commands typed in the `:` command-line. There were no variables in `ex`, so there's no way to specify them. When typing a command interactively, you'd probably use `<C-R>=` to insert variable contents:

```
:sleep <C-R>=timetowait<CR>m<CR>
```

... but in a script, `:execute` must be used. All the literal parts of the Ex command must be quoted (single or double quotes), and then concatenated with the variables:

```
execute 'sleep' timetowait . 'm'
```

#### Your problem

For a syntax script, you'd use `execute`. Additionally, please note that **string concatenation in Vim is done with `.`, not with `+`**. (Also note that I use single quotes to avoid escaping of the backslashes.)

```
execute 'syn match Title /\%>0l\%<' . b:title_until . 'l.*/'
```

Alternatively, you can use `printf()`; this is less cluttered when there are multiple variables. However, here you need to consider that `%` must be doubled:

```
execute printf('syn match Title /\%%>0l\%%<%sl.*/', b:title_until)
```

#### Final tips

The `\%>0l` is superfluous and can be omitted, as it will always match: there are no negative lines.

Comment: Thanks for the extended explanation. I guess the `+` for string concatenation was pure ignorance on my part... but the other stuff would have been impossible to figure out on my own.